# typescript ngx-google-places-autocomplete options

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using **ngx-google-places-autocomplete** following the docs.

while setting autocomplete options, according to the docs, I should be able to set bounds as LatLngBoundsLiteral as reported [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions)

so, according to what I understand, something like this should be accepted:

.ts file

```
...
const placeSearchOptions = {
    componentRestrictions: {country:'it'},
    bounds:{
      north: this.area.latlong.lat + 0.1,
      south: this.area.latlong.lat - 0.1,
      east: this.area.latlong.lng + 0.1,
      west: this.area.latlong.lng - 0.1,
    }
  };
```

.html file

```
...
<input
      [hidden]="!_isNew"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Place on Google"
      aria-label="Place"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
      ngx-google-places-autocomplete
      [options]='placeSearchOptions'
      #placesRef="ngx-places"
      (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"
    />
...
```

The above code is not working, the search result is not bounded.

if I try to declare options as *ngx-google-places-autocomplete/objects/options/options* I will not be able to set bounds (*error: Type '{ north: number; south: number; east: number; west: number; }' is not assignable to type 'LatLngBounds'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'north' does not exist in type 'LatLngBounds'.*) even if according to to the docs bounds is defined as *Type:  LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral optional*.

What am I missing?

PS: I'm able to set options if I omit bounds:

```
const placeSearchOptions:Options = { //imported from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete/objects/options/options'
    componentRestrictions: {country:'it'},
  };//NO ERRORS
```

Comment: Have you tried to use LatLngBounds instead? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds you can use something like `bounds: { ne: { lat: number, lng: number }, sw: { lat: number, lng: number } }`. I did not test this but it should work. The documentation says you can use `LatLngBoundsLiteral` but your error is indicating it only accepts `LatLngBounds`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library is expecting `LatLngBounds` type and you are attempting to give it `LatLngBoundsLiteral` (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds). I'm not sure why they have that miss documented. You can always control click to see what types the function accepts. Also, check the version of the library. You should be able to make the same call with `LatLngBounds` like this:

```
{
  ...
  bounds: {
    ne: {
     lat: this.area.latlong.lat + 0.1,
     lng: this.area.latlong.lng + 0.1
    },
    sw: {
     lat: this.area.latlong.lat - 0.1,
     lng: this.area.latlong.lng - 0.1
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Type '{ ne: { lat: any; lng: any; }; sw: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LatLngBounds'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ne' does not exist in type 'LatLngBounds'. -----
LatLngBounds has no setter nor constructor

Comment: I'm using a different library that requires the data structure like this: `{ northeast: { latitude: number, longitude: number } }`. You can give that a try

Comment: That LatLngBound type is not the same as the one specified in the google maps docs. Just seeing now, they expect an interface here https://github.com/skynet2/ngx-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/src/objects/latLngBounds.ts. I'm not sure how that is created though

Comment: a cant see any link to the library u used.. typo?

Comment: The link above was just to show what type is expected in the library that you are using. You might have better luck using an @googlemaps library like this one, `@googlemaps/js-api-loader`. Those are the libraries that are currently supported by Google. I actually use a server-side library for my requests `@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js`. You can always proxy requests through your API if you only need calculations.